# react-horizontal-scrolling-menu scrolling error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, horizontal-scrolling

**Hello, I'm having a problem with react-horizontal-scrolling-menu
, when scrolling, it scrolls to the right a lot, and the rest of the elements disappear, and when you add overflowX: 'scroll' to the BOX, the scroll doesn't work until after the first click

Plus LeftArrow, RightArrow don't work

Take a look at the code**

[error img here]
[image: 1]

```
<Box component="div" sx={{position:'relative', width:'100%',p:'20px'}}>
        <HorizontalScrollbar data={bodyParts} bodyParts={bodyParts} bodyPart={bodyPart} setBodyPart={setBodyPart}/>
  </Box>
```

**HorizontalScrollba**

```
  import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { ScrollMenu, VisibilityContext } from 'react-horizontal-scrolling-menu';
import { Box, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import BodyPart from './BodyPart';
import RightArrowIcon from '../assets/icons/right-arrow.png';
import LeftArrowIcon from '../assets/icons/left-arrow.png';

const LeftArrow = () => {
  const { scrollPrev } = useContext(VisibilityContext);

  return (
    <Typography onClick={() => scrollPrev()} className="right-arrow">
      <img src={LeftArrowIcon} alt="right-arrow" />
    </Typography>
  );
};

const RightArrow = () => {
  const { scrollNext } = useContext(VisibilityContext);

  return (
    <Typography onClick={() => scrollNext()} className="left-arrow" >
      <img src={RightArrowIcon} alt="right-arrow"/>
    </Typography>
  );
};

const HorizontalScrollbar = ({ data, bodyParts, setBodyPart, bodyPart }) => (
  <Box mt={4} sx={{position:'static'}}>
  <ScrollMenu LeftArrow={LeftArrow} RightArrow={RightArrow}>
    {data.map((item) => (
      <Box
        key={item.id || item}
        itemId={item.id || item}
        title={item.id || item}
        m="0 40px"
      >
         <BodyPart item={item} setBodyPart={setBodyPart} bodyPart={bodyPart} /> 
      </Box>
    ))}
  </ScrollMenu>
  </Box>
);

export default HorizontalScrollbar;
```

Comment: I solved the space issue with overflowX: 'scroll' but LeftArrow={LeftArrow} RightArrow={RightArrow} is not working

Answer (score 2):

install npm i react-horizontal-scrolling-menu@2.7.1, the latest 3.0.1 version has some issues regarding overflow

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

**I'm doing the same project and I got some errors**

It works with me:

```
npm i react-horizontal-scrolling-menu@2.7.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck here but I did a little hack to move on like I just copied the package.json from the git(link was mentioned in the description) and run the command 'npm install' and it start working.

I suggest you also do the same so you can move and after the installation look for an error or the problem
Happy Learning

Answer (score 0):

use Button rather than Typography :

```
const LeftArrow = () => {
  const { scrollPrev } = useContext(VisibilityContext);

  return (
    <Button onClick={() => scrollPrev()} className="right-arrow">
      <img src={LeftArrowIcon} alt="right-arrow" />
    </Button>
  );
};
```

This works as intended.

Comment: scrollPrev and scrollNext is undefined. I am using 3.2.2 version

Answer (score 0):

just add CSS in App.css file

```css
.react-horizontal-scrolling-menu--inner-wrapper{
    width: inherit !important;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).